# Add Discovery WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

i try to add Discovery to my WCF service according this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456783.aspx

This is My main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type.
    using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MySampleWCFService)))
    {
        // Add a ServiceDiscoveryBehavior
        serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());

        // ...
        // Add ServiceDiscoveryBehavior
        //serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());

        // Add a UdpDiscoveryEndpoint
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());

        Uri uri = new Uri("http://" + "10.161.150.250" + ":8733/MySampleWCFService");
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(uri);

        WCFServiceHostingInWinService.MySampleWCFService service = new MySampleWCFService();
        // Send to my service 2 numbers and received their value
        Console.WriteLine(service.Add(11, 12)); 
        EndpointAddress eee = FindCalculatorServiceAddress();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

FindCalculatorServiceAddress method:

```
    static EndpointAddress FindCalculatorServiceAddress()
    {
        // Create DiscoveryClient
        DiscoveryClient discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());

        // Find ICalculatorService endpoints            
        FindResponse findResponse = discoveryClient.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(IMySampleWCFService)));

        if (findResponse.Endpoints.Count > 0)
        {
            return findResponse.Endpoints[0].Address;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And get an error under:

```
// Add ServiceDiscoveryBehavior
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
```

**The value could not be added to the collection, as the collection already contains an item of the same type: 'System.ServiceModel.Discovery.ServiceDiscoveryBehavior'. This collection only supports one instance of each type.**

Answer (score 0):

You can clean Behaviors array, before adding new one.

```
// Add ServiceDiscoveryBehavior
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.RemoveAll<ClientCredentials>();
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
```

Comment: Same error, i don't even sure that my main code is OK,  start from URI uri = ... works fine but the code before need to come in this order ?